# How to use namedQueries in Grails 1.3.7 with object containing object?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have these classes:

```
class Category {
  Set usersLinked
  def hasMany = [usersLinked:CategoryUserLink]  
  static namedQueries = {
    getAuthorizedBusiness { auser ->
        eq "business", true
        usersLinked{
            eq "user", auser
            type{
                eq "name", "Authorized"
            }
        }            
    }
  }
}
class CategoryUserLink {
  User user
  CategoryType type
  Category category
}
```

When I querying on it with a `namedQuery` or a `createCriteria` I receive an error:

```
Category.getAuthorizedBusiness(user).list()
```

No such property usersLinked

Why?

I receive this error message:

```
 org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: userslinked of: lli.faqapp.domain.Category
    at grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.invokeMethod(HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:1223)
    at grails.orm.GormLabsHibernateCriteriaBuilder.super$3$invokeMethod(GormLabsHibernateCriteriaBuilder.groovy)
    at grails.orm.GormLabsHibernateCriteriaBuilder.methodMissing(GormLabsHibernateCriteriaBuilder.groovy:65)
    at lli.faqapp.domain.Category$__clinit__closure3_closure4.doCall(Category.groovy:84)
    at grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.invokeClosureNode(HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:1367)
    at grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.invokeMethod(HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:1117)
    at GormLabsGrailsPlugin$_registerCriteria_closure23_closure38.doCall(GormLabsGrailsPlugin.groovy:255)
    at lli.faqapp.domain.tests.CategoryTests.testSearchOnCategories(CategoryTests.groovy:39)
```

And after removing the plugin `GormLabs`, I start the integration test and I receive this message:

```
 org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: userslinked of: lli.faqapp.domain.Category
    at grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.invokeMethod(HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:1223)
    at lli.faqapp.domain.Category$__clinit__closure3_closure4.doCall(Category.groovy:84)
    at grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.invokeClosureNode(HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:1367)
    at grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.invokeMethod(HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:1117)
    at lli.faqapp.domain.tests.CategoryTests.testSearchOnCategories(CategoryTests.groovy:39)
```

Comment: Try it with out 'Set usersLinked', maybe it will help. And 'CategoryUserLink.type' is a String that will not have a property 'name'.

Comment: You're right about the tyope but in fact is an Object. I will try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hasMany` must be static - it's a property of the Class, not a specific instance. The Set `usersLinked` that it generates is instance-specific, but the `hasMany` declaration is for the Class.

Comment: Great ! I didn't see my mistake. Thanks a lot